# methods in a framework not responding to method calls

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.2

i have created a framework from an existing codebase by referring this link ["How to create a framework in iOS"](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/#list_contents). I was able to create a framework successfully. Now, i have imported this framework into a new project and tried to call the methods in it. But, there is no response from any of these methods. Even the NSLog statements in these methods are also not getting printed. There are no erros either. this is very frustrating. Can anyone help me out as to where i am going worng...

```
#import <framework/FIClassA.h>----> this is frame work import

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.viewController = [[[TrailOneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TrailOneViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
FIClassA *objA = [[FIClassA alloc] init];  //----> creating a object for a class in the framework
[objA methodA];   //----> calling a method in the framework

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the methods on your framework

Comment: Please check my updated question for a bit of code dean. I am calling that method from applicationdidFinishLaunching method...

Answer (score 0):

> i have imported this framework into a new project

Have you also added an #import for it in the particular class where you are using the methods you're calling?

Comment: yes, i have added #import <framework/framework.h> in my class file. Like i mentioned in my question, i am not even getting any import errors which means the import functionality is just fine.

Comment: what happens when you step through with the debugger?